# CakePHP security component is blackholing local client's call

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

So I have the `RestEventsController`, that has an `add` function which is using `EventsController's` logic. I have set up a local test client like this:

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class ClientController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Security', 'RequestHandler');

    public function index(){

    }

    public function request_add(){

        // remotely post the information to the server
        $link =  "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->webroot.'rest_events.json';

        $data = null;
        $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
        $data['Event']['user_id'] = '1234';
        $data['Event']['date'] = '2014-07-14';

        $response = $httpSocket->post($link, $data );
        $this->set('response_code', $response->code);
        $this->set('response_body', $response->body);

        $this -> render('/Client/request_add');
    }
}
```

It is supposed to make an HTTP request to the RESTful controller, but the response I get states that:

```
{"name":"The request has been black-holed","url":"\/application\/rest_events.json"}
```

Even though the `AppController's` before filter has the action unlocked, like following:

```
public function beforeFilter(){

if(in_array($this->params['controller'], array('rest_events'))){
    $this->Auth->allow();
    $this->Security->requireSecure();
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('index', 'add');
}else{
    $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->loggedIn());
    $this->set('current_user', $this->Auth->user());
}

}
```

What could possibly be wrong here?

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably `SecurityComponent::requireSecure()` vs `http`, ie use are not issuing a secure request.

### Unlocked actions still require secure

In case you expected that adding the actions to `SecurityComponent::$unlockedActions` would exclude them from the secure check, no, that's not the case, unlocked actions are only excluded from POST data validation and CSRF checks.

So either use `https`, or don't activate `requireSecure()` based on the requested action, something like:

```
if(!in_array($this->request->params['action'], $this->Security->unlockedActions)) {
    $this->Security->requireSecure();
}
```

### The cause for a blackholed request

Also note that you can use `SecurityComponent::$blackHoleCallback` to define a callback on your controller that catches the blackhole call and receives the type of error which you could then check or write to the logs.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Security->blackHoleCallback = 'blackhole';
}

public function blackhole($type) {
    debug($type);
    throw new BadRequestException(__d('cake_dev', 'The request has been black-holed'));
}
```

Note that once a blackhole callback is defined, the security component does not [**throw a `BadRequestException`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.2/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php#L334-L336) anymore, you'll have to do that on your own!

See **[Cookbook > Security Component > Handling blackhole callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks)** for more information.

Comment: I have remove the requireSecure, but still the GET reuqest is being made.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about @Domas, you never mentioned any GET request problems...

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I thought it was different question.

So I have defined the callback that catches the blackhole. The interesting part is that that debugged message is: `secure` and it all works well. But as soon as I comment the blackholecallback, it fails. 

Any idea of what can go wrong here?

Comment: @Domas The fact that the callback is triggered indicates that it _does not_ work well, it's just that the security component doesn't throw a `BadRequestException` by itself anymore in case a blackhole callback is defined (see my updated answer). So you'll still have to solve the problem that secure is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot! At least I got to know where the problem was.